# Python: cannot use a keyword as an expression

Tags: python

I am supposed to design a program that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each of the 12 months into an array. The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.

```
def main():
    months = [0] * 12
    name_months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun', \
               'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    def total(months):
        total = 0
        for num in months:
            total += num
        return total
    for index in range(12):
        print ('Enter the amount of rain in',
        months[index] = input(name_months[index] + ': '))
    print ('The total is', total(months), 'mm.')
    avarage = total(months) / 12.0
    print ('The avarage rainfall is', avarage, 'months')
    m_copy = months[0:]
    months.sort()
    lowest = months[0]
    print ('Lowest is', lowest, 'in',)
    lows = []
    for i in range (12):
        if m_copy[i] == lowest:
            lows.append( name_months[i] )
    for i in range (len(lows)):
        print (lows[i],)
        if i < len(lows)-1: print ('and',)
    print
    highest = months[11]
    print ('Highest is', highest, 'in',)
    highs = []
    for i in range (12):
        if m_copy[i] == highest:
            highs.append( name_months[i] )
    for i in range (len(highs)):
        print (highs[i],)        
        if i < len(highs)-1: print ('and',)
    print

main()
```

It keeps saying I cannot use a keyword as an expression, I have been staring at it for over an hour now I may have looked over something.

Comment: Could you edit your original post and format the code correctly using the {} braces.

Comment: Please don't shout even when it is done with just **bold** text. Please do not include 'problem' in your question title; give a summary of your problem. Somehow, I doubt if this code is an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: On what line is the error message?  That will tell you straight away where the problem is.

Comment: Is the problem that you're using Python 2.x on Python 3.x code? Python 2.x complains about the `print` on line 12 of your code, but the notation it complains about is the embedded assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error you mention, but your code seems to be confused in a way that's a bit too big to explain as a comment. You seem to be using a mix of Python 2 and Python 3 code, which won't work - for example, you seem to expect this:

```
print ('and',)
```

to print the string `'and'`, but supress the newline that `print` usually produces. In Python 2, it prints this:

```
('and',)
```

in Python 3, this:

```
'and'
```

in both cases *with* the newline.

This happens because the comma suppressed the newline in Python 2, but the brackets weren't part of the statement - so, you're telling it to print a one-item tuple.

In Python 3, it is a normal function call (so the brackets *are* part of it), and you can tell it to put an arbitrary string at the end after it has done printing - it defaults to a newline, but you can change it to, say, a space like this:

print('and', end=' ')

You also seem to expect:

```
print
```

to put a single blank line. In Python 2, it will. In Python 3, it won't do anything - you need to call the function now:

```
print()
```

You'll also run into problems with the way you're using input:

```
months[index] = input(name_months[index] + ': ')
```

In Python 2, using the `input` function at all, ever, was considered a bad idea, and it was generally recommended to use `raw_input` instead. Now `input` does what `raw_input` used to - namely, it returns a *string*. The rest of your code assumes that each `months[index]` will be a number, so that:

```
total += num
```

will do arithmetic. When `num` (which comes from `months`) is a string, you actually get an error. The way around this is to tell Python to turn it into a number after you get it:

```
months[index] = int(input(name_months[index] + ': '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python generally gives you the line number of the error and that will be invaluable in solving this problem.

If you're running this in Python 2, your *first* problem lies here:

```
print ('Enter the amount of rain in',
months[index] = input(name_months[index] + ': '))
```

You don't have a closing parenthesis on the first line and you have too many on the second.

When I change that to

```
print ('Enter the amount of rain in'),
months[index] = input(name_months[index] + ': ')
```

it works, albeit with strange list output formats, at least in Python 2.7 (v3 might be different):

```
Enter the amount of rain in Jan: 1
Enter the amount of rain in Feb: 2
Enter the amount of rain in Mar: 3
Enter the amount of rain in Apr: 4
Enter the amount of rain in May: 5
Enter the amount of rain in Jun: 6
Enter the amount of rain in Jul: 7
Enter the amount of rain in Aug: 8
Enter the amount of rain in Sep: 9
Enter the amount of rain in Oct: 0
Enter the amount of rain in Nov: 1
Enter the amount of rain in Dec: 2
('The total is', 48, 'mm.')
('The avarage rainfall is', 4.0, 'months')
('Lowest is', 0, 'in')
('Oct',)

('Highest is', 9, 'in')
('Sep',)
```

---

By the way, I wouldn't be implementing a function like `total()` when Python already provides a perfectly good `sum()` which does what you want.